# Format cell color according to output

Tags: excel, vba, function, if-statement, user-defined-functions

I built a function which will compare two adjacent cells in Excel and return text values as output.

I want to format the second cell according to the output.

```vb
Function COMPARE(ByVal Cell1 As Range, ByVal Cell2 As Range) As String
Dim Result As String
If Cell1 = Cell2 Then
    COMPARE = ""
ElseIf Cell1 > Cell2 Then
    COMPARE = "Kapa-Reduzierung"
    Cell2.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 153)
ElseIf Cell1 < Cell2 Then
    COMPARE = "Kapa-Erhöhung"
    Cell2.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
Else: COMPARE = "Input Error"
End If
End Function
```

How to write the following?

```
Cell2.Interior.Color = RGB........
```

Comment: If you're using the function on a worksheet as a formula then it can't change the colour.  It can only return the value to put in the cell.  [Description of limitations of custom functions in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1)

Comment: If you were to create a Sub containing the line `Sheet1.Range("C1") = COMPARE(Sheet1.Range("A1"), Sheet1.Range("B1"))` then your code works fine as it's not being used as a formula.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? (Change the Workbook name, the Worksheet name and Cell Ranges to suit your requirements.)

```
Private strCOMPARE As String

Sub CheckCells(ByVal Cell1 As Range, ByVal Cell2 As Range)
    
    If Cell1.Value = Cell2.Value Then
        
        strCOMPARE = ""
        
    Else
        
        If Cell1 > Cell2 Then
            
            strCOMPARE = "Kapa-Reduzierung"
            
            Cell2.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 153)
            
        Else
            
            If Cell1 < Cell2 Then
                
                strCOMPARE = "Kapa-Erhohung"
                
                Cell2.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
                
            Else
                
                strCOMPARE = "Input Error"
                
            End If
            
        End If
        
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub Test()
    
    With Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
        Call CheckCells(.Range("A1"), .Range("B1"))
        
    End With
    
    MsgBox strCOMPARE
    
End Sub
```